# Android studio Shortcuts for MAC Not Visible

Tags: android, macos, android-studio, android-studio-2.2

I recently switched my Android Development from Linux to Mac and have been facing a lot of issues especially with the shortcuts keys in Android Studio. I am getting around this as I have not previously used Mac either.

However, I have been facing a very weird issue wherein the shortcut keys are not visible inside Android studio and are showing up as boxes (maybe MAC does not have those icons) whereas in Options menu on Top these icons are showing up correctly. I am attaching a screen shot here for reference. Is there someway to fix this. I find it tough to work without those keyboard shortcuts and would be really helpful if someone can help.

In the image below you can see that the settings page for setting custom keymap in the Editor Actions is showing buttons but with Boxes for the Command/Options/Shift key, but is working fine when I check the options available in Files/Edit/View etc.

Also, if you have some other tips regarding this getting started with Mac for development for smooth transition, I would very much welcome it.

[image: reference].

Comment: Maybe, it could help: https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/keyboard-shortcuts.html

Comment: This just gives a list of shortcuts, no resolution for the issue.

Comment: Try Intellij IDEA instead. If that doesn't work, yeah, it's an encoding / missing font issue. Maybe need to submit bug report

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was resolved with Android Studio 3.0. I just removed all instances of earlier Android Studio and made a fresh download from developer's website for Android.