# Android Studio keys not visible in Key Promoter

Tags: android, macos, encoding, android-studio-2.2

I am using a plugin in Android Studio, key promoter, which is a great tool as I just switched from Linux to Mac and has been a lot helpful. However, at times there comes a window when I am not able to view the key that is shown in the Key Promoter Dialog. I am attaching a screen shot here for your reference. I have been facing similar [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40460961/android-studio-shortcuts-for-mac-not-visible) in Android studio, which is still pending resolution.[image]